# How do I reaplace the second space of my text with sed?

Tags: sed, replace

I want to change the second space of every line by a -
My file is:

> KX300221.1 Agkonia_ovifera GBA027

> KX300312.1 Pronola_magniplaga MZ183

> KX360845.1 Rhabdatomis_mandana MZ190

> KX360802.1 Balbura_intervenata GBA020

> KC571047.1 Abrochocis_esperanza CHS-CR118

> KJ378646.1 Acsala_anomala NOC14838

> KF533447.1 Automolis_ferrigera NSGJZ020

I tried with sed:

```
sed -E 's/^>([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/>\1 \2-\3/' table_ids.txt > seq_ids.txt
```

and:

```
sed '2s/ /-/' table_ids.txt 

sed -E 's/^>([^\s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s]+)/>\1 \2-\3/' table_ids.txt

sed -E 's/([^[:space:]]+) ([^[:space:]]+) ([^[:space:]]+)/\1 \2-\3/' table_ids.txt
```

And any of the options worked. I get the same:

> KX300221.1 Agkonia_ovifera GBA027

> KX300312.1 Pronola_magniplaga MZ183

> KX360845.1 Rhabdatomis_mandana MZ190

> KX360802.1 Balbura_intervenata GBA020

> KC571047.1 Abrochocis_esperanza CHS-CR118

> KJ378646.1 Acsala_anomala NOC14838

> KF533447.1 Automolis_ferrigera NSGJZ020

And I expected:

> KX300221.1 Agkonia_ovifera-GBA027

> KX300312.1 Pronola_magniplaga-MZ183

> KX360845.1 Rhabdatomis_mandana-MZ190

> KX360802.1 Balbura_intervenata-GBA020

> KC571047.1 Abrochocis_esperanza-CHS-CR118

> KJ378646.1 Acsala_anomala-NOC14838

> KF533447.1 Automolis_ferrigera-NSGJZ020

Comment: You can use: `sed 's/ /-/2' file`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then format your input and output as Code Blocks, just like your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/ /-/2' file

KX300221.1 Agkonia_ovifera-GBA027
KX300312.1 Pronola_magniplaga-MZ183
KX360845.1 Rhabdatomis_mandana-MZ190
KX360802.1 Balbura_intervenata-GBA020
KC571047.1 Abrochocis_esperanza-CHS-CR118
KJ378646.1 Acsala_anomala-NOC14838
KF533447.1 Automolis_ferrigera-NSGJZ020
```